# How to track sign in count of user in identity server 4

Tags: asp.net-core, identityserver4

I want to track user sign in count in my identity server 4 implicit flow for SPA client.

Comment: Show us your attempt.

Comment: Please take a look at this post  [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)